# replacement / substition with Haskell regex libraries

Tags: regex, haskell

Is there a high-level API for doing search-and-replace with regexes in Haskell? In particular, I'm looking at the `Text.Regex.TDFA` or `Text.Regex.Posix` packages. I'd really like something of type:

```
f :: Regex -> (ResultInfo -> m String) -> String -> m String
```

so, for example, to replace "dog" with "cat" you could write

```
runIdentity . f "dog" (return . const "cat")    -- :: String -> String
```

or do more advanced things with the monad, like counting occurrences, etc.

Haskell documentation for this is pretty lacking. Some low-level API notes are [here](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2007/02/27/a-haskell-regular-expression-tutorial/).

Answer (score 31):

How about the [`Text.Regex.subRegex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.92/docs/Text-Regex.html) in package `regex-compat`?

```
Prelude> import Text.Regex (mkRegex, subRegex)

Prelude> :t mkRegex
mkRegex :: String -> Regex

Prelude> :t subRegex
subRegex :: Regex -> String -> String -> String

Prelude> subRegex (mkRegex "foo") "foobar" "123"
"123bar"
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any existing function that creates this functionality, but I think that I'd end up using something like the [`AllMatches [] (MatchOffset, MatchLength)` instance of `RegexContent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/0.93.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html) to simulate it:

```
replaceAll :: RegexLike r String => r -> (String -> String) -> String -> String
replaceAll re f s = start end
  where (_, end, start) = foldl' go (0, s, id) $ getAllMatches $ match re s
        go (ind,read,write) (off,len) =
          let (skip, start) = splitAt (off - ind) read 
              (matched, remaining) = splitAt len matched 
          in (off + len, remaining, write . (skip++) . (f matched ++))

replaceAllM :: (Monad m, RegexLike r String) => r -> (String -> m String) -> String -> m String
replaceAllM re f s = do
  let go (ind,read,write) (off,len) = do
      let (skip, start) = splitAt (off - ind) read 
      let (matched, remaining) = splitAt len matched 
      replacement <- f matched
      return (off + len, remaining, write . (skip++) . (replacement++))
  (_, end, start) <- foldM go (0, s, return) $ getAllMatches $ match re s
  start end
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on @rampion's answer, but with the typo fixed so it doesn't just `<<loop>>`:

```
replaceAll :: Regex -> (String -> String) -> String -> String
replaceAll re f s = start end
  where (_, end, start) = foldl' go (0, s, id) $ getAllMatches $ match re s
        go (ind,read,write) (off,len) =
            let (skip, start) = splitAt (off - ind) read 
                (matched, remaining) = splitAt len start 
            in (off + len, remaining, write . (skip++) . (f matched ++))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replaceAll` from the [Data.Text.ICU.Replace module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-regex-replace-0.1.1.1/docs/Data-Text-ICU-Replace.html).

```
Prelude> :set -XOverloadedStrings
Prelude> import Data.Text.ICU.Replace
Prelude Data.Text.ICU.Replace> replaceAll "cat" "dog" "Bailey is a cat, and Max is a cat too."
"Bailey is a dog, and Max is a dog too."
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this approach fit you.

```
import Data.Array (elems)
import Text.Regex.TDFA ((=~), MatchArray)

replaceAll :: String -> String -> String -> String        
replaceAll regex new_str str  = 
    let parts = concat $ map elems $ (str  =~  regex :: [MatchArray])
    in foldl (replace' new_str) str (reverse parts) 

  where
     replace' :: [a] -> [a] -> (Int, Int) -> [a]
     replace' new list (shift, l)   = 
        let (pre, post) = splitAt shift list
        in pre ++ new ++ (drop l post)
```

Answer (score 1):

For doing “search-and-replace” with “more advanced things with the monad, like counting occurrences, etc,” I recommend [`Replace.Megaparsec.streamEditT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:streamEditT).

See the package README for specific examples of how to count occurrences.